# C#: 2 4 Digit numbers into 2 bytes each and convert that to a Uint32

Tags: c#, integer, byte, bitwise-operators, converters

I got 2 4 digit numbers.

I need to get them in 2 Bytes each and convert them afterwards to Uint32.

Am i doing it correct?

```
byte[] data = new byte[4];
byte b1 = (byte)OldPin, b2 = (byte)(OldPin >> 8);
byte b3 = (byte)NewPin, b4 = (byte)(NewPin >> 8);
data[0] = b1;
data[1] = b2;
data[2] = b3;
data[3] = b4;

var result = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0)
```

And additionally i need to do the same, but 1 of the 4 digit numbers is a string and the other 0.

```
byte[] data = new byte[4];
byte b1 = (byte)0, b2 = (byte)0;
byte b3 = (byte)Convert.ToInt64(enteredPin), b4 = (byte)(Convert.ToInt64(enteredPin) >> 8);
data[0] = b1;
data[1] = b2;
data[2] = b3;
data[3] = b4;
var result = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0)
```

Comment: And what is the question? Note: `BitConverter` is almost always a bad choice - it is CPU-endian

Comment: If my result is correct in both cases.

Comment: we can't tell you that without discussing endiannness; what is the required endianness? by which I mean: "convert them afterwards to Uint32" it inherently an ambiguous statement; there are (at least) 2 meanings of that - depending on big-endian vs little-endian; likewise, how we write the values in the first place. We really need to discuss **bytes** here. Is there a specification that mentions endianness?

Comment: example: https://sharplab.io/#v2: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

Comment: you can see in there the same bytes i.e. the 0x56781234, but: the order of the bytes, and what that *means* is a question of endianness

Comment: OldPin and NewPin are both longs

I need to combine these two into one Uint32 Value, by filling the first 2 bytes with OldPin and the last 2 bytes with NewPin.

Comment: Did you mean that with endianness?

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is inherently ambiguous; there is no single meaning of the line:

> I need to get them in 2 Bytes each and convert them afterwards to Uint32.

By which I mean; say we have the 4-digit number 4660 - which is, at least by human meaning, the bytes (displayed on hex) `12 34` as a 16-bit payload (and the bytes `00 00 12 34` as a 32-bit payload). The problem is: the bytes `12 34` is just *one interpretation*; humans tend to think in big-endian terms (meaning: when we write a number, we write the "big end" first, i.e. in decimal we write the thousands then the hundreds then the tens then the digits); that's *not how most computers work*; they are often actually *little endian* at the octet level, so to most computers, the decimal 4660 is actually the bytes `34 12` (assuming we mean a 16-bit number; it would be `34 12 00 00` as a 32-bit number).

So: we need to discuss and define what endianness we want *at every stage*. That's also why `BitConverter` is usually useless - since it is CPU-endian, meaning: "whatever endianness the current CPU uses". This is often fine for in-process work, but is useless when sharing data with the world in a way that needs to give the same result on any machine!

So: we need to use endianness-aware conversions. Fortunately, this is pretty easy in modern .NET; consider:

```cs
using System;
using System.Buffers.Binary;

short oldPin = 0x1234, newPin = 0x5678;
Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[4];
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16LittleEndian(bytes, oldPin);
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16LittleEndian(bytes.Slice(2), newPin);
var final = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32LittleEndian(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(final); // 1450709556
```

If we want to use big-endian conversions instead: just replace `LittleEndian` with `BigEndian` and you're done. I've used little-endian notation here because it is a common choice in IO work, but in reality: you need to consult your specification and use the *correct* endianness - and I can't tell you which that is. It might even be different for different parts of that operation!

Comment: ok i did not know that the Converter shoud not be used. I'm new to bitwise operators and such. 
I'll try your example. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jules this whole thing *could* be as simple as `(oldPin << 16) | newPin`, but again: without discussing endianness: very hard to know for sure!

Comment: @Jules it isn't quite that `BitConverter` "shouldn't be used"; more: if you use it, you should be *aware of what it is doing*, and the implications of that; although in reality, it is usually a poor choice compared to the newer `BinaryPrimitives` API